# Application insights end to end transaction details does not show whole sequence of telemetry

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

We are having multiple microservices and we have application insights enabled on all of them.When i see end to end transaction details for a scenario like  UI calls Service A which does some db operations and then calls service B which inturn does some db operations and calls service C. In this kind of scenario my end to end trasaction only shows me first level of calls (i.e. Service A , db operations and call to service B) and after that just says "More details for this call are not available due to sampling".

I have even tried removing "AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor" from app insights config but still the same thing. Below is the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Which SDKs are you using in all the microsevices in question (eg. .NET, Java, Node.js, ...)? Which versions are they? Do you have any custom telemetry processors configured?

Comment: These are .NET based web api applications. We are using latest version of Microsofts app insights sdk and also using application insights owin extensions https://github.com/marcinbudny/applicationinsights-owinextensions

Comment: we have only a custom telemetry initializer which adds some details related to tenant and other application related stuff

Answer (score 4):

While the message on screen only mentions sampling, it more generically means that within the next microservice's telemetry, nothing was found with the same operation id - but that it found reason to expect that there should be telemetry.

**The fix for this is to ensure that operation id (and parent id) is being propagated to all microservices and is used in the telemetry recorded by each microservice.**

Typically, when using the latest Application Insights SDKs, service-to-service calls over HTTP are bound to share an operation id via [correlation headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/application-insights-correlation#correlation-headers). These headers exist on the request to an instrumented microservice and that service's response back. The existence of these headers establish that "reason to expect that there should be telemetry".

Because the portal found evidence those headers existed but did not find telemetry from the next service (and sampling is disabled), it looks like that telemetry has been recorded with a *different* operation id in the next service. The additional library you're using (owinextensions) [seems to overwrite operation id with its own generation](https://github.com/marcinbudny/applicationinsights-owinextensions#changing-how-ids-are-generated) and [instructs to remove the built-in initializers that the SDK uses to make correlation happen](https://github.com/marcinbudny/applicationinsights-owinextensions#required-steps).

To implement the fix bolded above in this situation, I would either:

- Find a way to go without owinextensions and restore the default initializers
- [Use owinextensions' separate operation id persistence headers](https://github.com/marcinbudny/applicationinsights-owinextensions#passing-operationid-via-header)
- [Combine the documented sample code for reading default correlation headers in OWIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/application-insights-custom-operations-tracking#http-request-in-owin-self-hosted-app) with [owinextensions' ability to change its operation id generation](https://github.com/marcinbudny/applicationinsights-owinextensions#changing-how-ids-are-generated).

Comment: I could see the problem... The client calling the next microservice was not propagating the operation I'd properly. Now I see both microservice calls under same operation id but still it does not show as hierarchy... So still only one level with two independent calls. No parent child relationship

Comment: For hierarchy, you need to have parent id propagating as well as operation id. A request telemetry should have its parent id set to the id of the dependency that triggered it. A dependency should have a parent id set to the id of the request that it is contained in. This should (hopefully!) work out-of-the-box with the default initializers.